# What's the preferable way to draw a collection of lines in an NSView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

Let's say there's a collection of lines in some instance variable in my `NSView` instance. This collection stays the same over time. How would you draw the collection?

I currently draw to an `NSImage` when the collection is set up, and override `-drawRect:` to display the image's contents. Is there a better way?

Tested out two options so far :

1. Draw to an `NSImage` when the collection is set up, and override `-drawRect:` to display the image's contents.
2. Draw the list of lines in `-drawRect:` itself.

[Benchmarks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/niDod.jpg) show the image drawing to be much faster. If I resize my window and it has, say; 10000 line segments, then the resize is incredibly slow if I use the second option. Not so with the first.

What's the preferable (eg. most efficient) strategy?

---

Example code :

```
- (void)drawSegments:(NSSize)size segments:(segment *)segments count:(int)nb_segments {
    NSBitmapImageRep *lineRepresentation = [self bitmapForPixels:linePixels];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:
     [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithBitmapImageRep:lineRepresentation]];
    memset(*linePixels, 0, pixels*4);
    NSBezierPath *path = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    for (int i=0 ; i<nb_segments ; i++) {
        [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(segments[i].x1, segments[i].y1)];
        [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(segments[i].x2, segments[i].y2)];
    }
    [[NSColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
    [lineRepresentation release];
}

- (NSBitmapImageRep *)bitmapForPixels:(int **)pixels {
    NSBitmapImageRep *representation = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithBitmapDataPlanes:((unsigned char **)pixels)
                                                                           pixelsWide:SCREEN_SIZE.width
                                                                           pixelsHigh:SCREEN_SIZE.height
                                                                        bitsPerSample:8
                                                                      samplesPerPixel:4
                                                                             hasAlpha:true
                                                                             isPlanar:false
                                                                       colorSpaceName:NSDeviceRGBColorSpace
                                                                         bitmapFormat:NSAlphaFirstBitmapFormat
                                                                          bytesPerRow:4*SCREEN_SIZE.width
                                                                         bitsPerPixel:32];
    return representation;
}
```

Comment: I would first try `NSBezierPath`. A Bezier path can contain any arbitrary collection of connected and unconnected line segments, and is highly optimized. Other optimizations will require more details (are all of the lines visible, or only a subset, etc., etc.).

Comment: Thanks, worth a try.

Comment: Drawing a whole bezier path in `-drawRect:' still causes some lagging while resizing, which is not the case when I draw the image.

Comment: Are all lines visible? Add your code to the question please.

Comment: My next suggestion would be to try setting `canDrawConcurrently` to `true`. You must ensure your `-drawRect:` method is thread safe (i.e. you obtain a thread-safe copy of your `NSBezierPath` (for example) and then use that copy the draw the lines. Pre-drawing into an image is all well and good, but you're just duplicating Cocoa's work, because that's all `-drawRect:` really does (render your view and save the pixelated results).

Comment: It's for an app that determines intersections of line segments. Currently I draw to a pixel buffer and then display it in `-drawRect:`. Drawing the lines is done once to a pixel buffer (using `NSBezierPath`, see code). Drawing intersections is done by directly altering the pixel buffer. Are there better ways? There may be up to 50000 lines and many more intersections. All lines tend to be visible (app covers screen). Current results are already good enough but I wanted to see if there are better ways. I also experimented with OpenGL, which is faster than the pixel buffer + `NSBitmapImageRep`.